# "Fetch as Google" is showing an empty page for inline JS while page renders fine on browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, seo, google-search-console, google-crawlers

I have a very simple static HTML page with just one div. I have some static data defined in `<head>` and want jquery to iterate over this structure and append this inside the div `startHere`.

```
<body>
    <div id='startHere'></div>
    <script>
      $("#startHere").append(<function to generate html from the data>)
    </script>
  </body>
```

This works well in browsers and I see the content that I want to see. However when I try to use "Fetch as Google", I see an empty page with just the header.

The status of the request is shows as `completed` in the google tool.

Any idea why this page shows empty?

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: I'm fairly sure Google's crawler won't execute this type of javascript, so it renders the page as empty.

Comment: @guest271314 I want to see the same page as it renders in the browser (with by new HTML appended inside the div)

Comment: @jonmrich Any ideas on how to get around this? Putting this logic inside `document.ready` doesn't help as well

Comment: See https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html, https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/10/updating-our-technical-webmaster.html

Comment: Thanks @guest271314 for the link. However the links mentions that the page should be rendered like a modern browser. My robots.txt has no restrictions. `User-agent: *
Disallow:`

As mentioned, my page renders alright in the browser.

Comment: Why do you use `Disallow`? See http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55799/is-my-whole-site-is-blocked-by-this-disallow. See also [Googlebot and empty CORS responses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40965697/googlebot-and-empty-cors-responses/41134627#41134627)

Comment: Not sure if it was clear in the text above but it was empty after `Disallow`.

As per http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html, 

`To allow all robots complete access

User-agent: *
Disallow:`

Comment: Why do you want to view the same page as it renders in browser at webmaster tools? Does the function call dynamically add links or images to the `document`?

Comment: Yes, this js function add text and images to the page.

Pardon my ignorance but isn't the purpose of "Fetch as Google" is to see how the crawler sees your page and indexes it?